# Java - Xuggle Crashing on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: java, xuggle, mediainfo

I am using xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar file in my Java application (to extract media information like duration, bitrate etc), and it crashes the whole application at "container.open()". It generates a log file containing the following message:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000011226520, pid=15980, tid=16324
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [xuggle7723496972795585954.dll+0x736520]
---------
```

Can you provide jar file for xuggle 5.5 version. If not please suggest a good API / framework which provides media information.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Xuggle seems to have a problem running with a 64 bit Java version.

Try it with a 32 bit Java version.

I know it's more a workaround than a solution, but since I switch to the 32 bit Java version, I didn't experiment this problem anymore.

Hope this help.